# What does this warning message mean when I upload a module to HackageDB?

Tags: haskell, hackage

When I'm uploading a module to Hackage, I get the following error message:

"Exposed modules use unallocated top-level names"

I am declaring the module as an exposed module in the .cabal file. Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: Ignore it - the convention for hierarchical names is valuable for the standard libraries and libraries that want to be "canonical" but onerous otherwise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems hackage enforces that you use one of the common top-level names in the [hierarchy](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hierarchical_module_names) for your modules, e.g. `Data`, `Control`, `System`.

So you can't name your banana catapult library `Banana.Catapult`, but rather `System.Banana.Catapult` or wherever you think your lib would fit.